# export to print is not working in my page

Tags: c#

i am having a issue while printing multiple pages in c#. I tried all possibilities but is not fixed yet. My issue is that i want to print 1 row per page but it is not doing so. currently it is printing only first row on all pages. . Here is the code
In PrintPageEvent

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{

string cell = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
// string itemx = dr["item_id"].ToString().PadLeft(6,'0'); 
string itemx = cell.PadLeft(6, '0');
string item2 = "*" + itemx + "*";
string item3 = "*UMS" + itemx + "*";
e.Graphics.DrawString(itemx, new Font("Free 3 of 9", 30, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black,          xValue, yValue);
e.Graphics.DrawString(item3, new Font("Courier New", 14, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black,  xValue, yValue2);
// yValue = yValue + 70;
// yValue2 = yValue2 + 70;
if (totalnumberA < dt.Rows.Count)
{
e.HasMorePages = true;
totalnumberA++; //return;
//eturn;
}
else
{
e.HasMorePages = false;
//totalnumberA++; //return;
}

}
```

and my button event is this

```
try
{
DBConnection DB = new DBConnection();
DB.cnTransact.Open();
string sql = "select * from tbl_items where serialNo='122'";
cm = new SqlCommand(sql, DB.cnTransact);
SqlDataAdapter people = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
people.Fill(dt);

 //foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) 
}


catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{

}

totalnumberA = 0; 
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();  
PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
dialog.Document = printDocument;
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
dialog.ShowDialog(); 

printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocumentOnPrintPage; 
printDocument.DocumentName = "Barcodes";
printDocument.Print(); - See more at:
```

Answer (score 1):

The PrintPage event is fired for every page printed in the document. So in your code for every page you begin a new or loop which is initialized to zero, eventually printing your first row. So remove the for loop, and use totalNumberA as an index to your row.

```
string cell = dt.Rows[totalnumberA][0].ToString();

string itemx = cell.PadLeft(6, '0');
string item2 = "*" + itemx + "*";
string item3 = "*UMS" + itemx + "*";

e.Graphics.DrawString(itemx, new Font("Free 3 of 9", 30, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black,          xValue, yValue);
e.Graphics.DrawString(item3, new Font("Courier New", 14, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black,  xValue, yValue2);

if (totalnumberA < dt.Rows.Count)
{
    e.HasMorePages = true;
    totalnumberA++;
}
else
{
    e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```